# How to call to new object in promise join

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I use the promise join and I need to use send the data from the readFile to myFacade  (src) and my facade send obj to getA which latter on will be sent to arg[0]...

```
run = function (filePath) {
    return Promise.join(
        fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8')
            .then(myFacade)
            .then(getA),
        users.getUsersAsync(usersObj)
            .then(users.modifyRec.bind(null, process.env.us))
    ).then(function (args) {
            return runProc('run', args[0], args[1]);
....
```

To make this work not in promise you should do something like

```
  var parsed = new MyFacade(str);
   var attribute = parsed.getA()
```

This is the code which should be called

```
var yaml = require('yamljs');

function MyFacade(src) {
  this.data = yaml.parse(src);
}

MyFacade.prototype = {

  getA: function () {
    return this.data.def_types.web;
  },

  getB: function () {
    return this.data.conars;
  }

};

module.exports = MyFacade;
```

how to make it work with the promise chain above?

Comment: Just make two functions `myFacade` and `getA` that call `new MyFacade` and `instance.getAt()` respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass exactly the code you'd have used without promises as a callback:

```
return Promise.join(
    fs.readFileAsync(filePath, 'utf8')
        .then(function(str) {
            var parsed = new MyFacade(str);
            var attribute = parsed.getA()
            return attribute;
        }),
    users.getUsersAsync(usersObj)
        .then(users.modifyRec.bind(null, process.env.us)),
function(attr, rec) {
    return runProc('run', attr, rec);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using

```
.then(getA)
```

Which means "call the function `getA` on the result of the previous promise."  But you don't have a function `getA`; the result of the previous promise has a method `getA`.  You want [`call`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#callstring-propertyname--dynamic-arg---promise):

```
.call('getA')
```

As for

```
.then(myFacade)
```

There are two options.  One is a common thing to add to a constructor function:

```
function MyFacade(src) {
  if(!(this instanceof MyFacade)) return new MyFacade(src);
  this.data = yaml.parse(src);
}
```

This allows the constructor to be called without `new`.  Alternatively, you can pass an anonymous function to `then`:

```
.then(function(str) {
  return new MyFacade(str);
})
```

Comment: Thanks but what with the new keyword ?new MyFacade(str)